# Java: My new object instantiation is changing a previous object reference

Tags: java, object, reference, arraylist

I am trying to figure out what is going on here and would appreciate any help. I have a loop where I am creating new objects and then adding them to an ArrayList. But it seems as though each time through the loop the new object is actually also changing the previously created objects. I understand that the ArrayList actually only contains references to objects, but I thought by calling new each time through I would be creating new instances so each reference would be unique.

Here is the code:

```
void copyFields()
{
    String fruitStr = "apple red,banana yellow,orange orange,pear green,grape purple";

    String[][] fruitArray = new String[5][];
    String[] fruitPairs = fruitStr.split(",");
    int r = 0;
    for (String fruitPair : fruitPairs) 
    {
        fruitArray[r++] = fruitPair.split(" ");
    }

    ArrayList<Fruit> fruitList = new ArrayList<Fruit>();
    for (String[] f : fruitArray)
    {
        Fruit fruitObj = new Fruit(f[0],f[1]);
        fruitList.add(fruitObj);
    }
}
```

So at the end fruitList contains 5 objects - all identical to the last element in fruitArray (grape purple).

You can see I'm trying to go from a string that contains a list of fruit/color pairs, to a two-dimensional array, to an ArrayList of Fruit objects. I can verify each step is working correctly until I watch in the debugger as the fruitList is populated that each time through the for loop changes all previous objects in the fruitList.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Please show your code for `Fruit`. My guess is that you've got static fields which should be instance fields.

Comment: Thank you @JonSkeet you are absolutely right! Removed static and works fine now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested your code and it works with a classic `Fruit` implementation :

```
public class Fruit {
    private String name;
    private String color;

    public Fruit(String name, String color) {
        this.color = color;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

So i suppose that the fields are `static`:

```
public class Fruit {
    private static String name;
    private static String color;

    public Fruit(String name, String color) {
        Fruit.color = color;
        Fruit.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right. Thank you so much. That's what I get for coding at 4am! Removed static from Fruit fields and it works fine. Doh!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need your intermediate `fruitArray` somewhere else in your app, you can simplify your code as follow:

```
String pairsStr = "apple red,banana yellow,orange orange,pear green,grape purple";
ArrayList<Fruit> fruits = new ArrayList<Fruit>();

String[] pairs = pairsStr.split(",");
for (String pairStr : pairs) {
    String[] pair = pairStr.split(" ");
    fruits.add(new Fruit(pair[0], pair[1]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created the following example and tested it with [compileonline](http://www.compileonline.com) and had no problems. The problem is maybe in your `Fruid` class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class HelloWorld{
    public static void main(String []args){
        String fruitStr = "apple red,banana yellow,orange orange,pear green,grape purple";

        String[][] fruitArray = new String[5][];
        String[] fruitPairs = fruitStr.split(",");
        int r = 0;
        for (String fruitPair : fruitPairs) 
        {
            fruitArray[r++] = fruitPair.split(" ");
        }
        ArrayList<String> testList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String[] f : fruitArray)
        { 
            String testString = f[0] + " + " + f[1];
            System.out.println(testString);
            testList.add(testString);
        }
        for (String s: testList) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
     }
}
```

Result:

```
apple + red
banana + yellow
orange + orange
pear + green
grape + purple
apple + red
banana + yellow
orange + orange
pear + green
grape + purple
```